# Calculate $\int_{\pi^2}^{4\pi^2} \frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate $$\int_{\pi^2}^{4\pi^2} \frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}} \,dx.$$
I calculated the integral and got $2\sin(\sqrt{x})$ as a result, but for $x=\pi^2$ and $x=4\pi^2$ we get that $2\sin(\sqrt{\pi^2})=0$ and $2\sin(\sqrt{4\pi^2})=0$ So the Riemann integral will be $0-0=0$ which is not true, as you can see from ploting $2\sin(\sqrt{x})$.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with what you did...I even plotted $2\sin\sqrt{x}$ as well as the integrand and it looks fine. And Maple agrees with 0.

Comment: Even the graph of the function seems to agree with the result: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eeftq8bsmed

Answer (score 9):

> $$\int_{\pi^2}^{4\pi^2} \frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}} \,dx.$$

Letting $u=\sqrt{x}$, we have $du=\large\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx\;$ or $\;2\,du = \large\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}},\;$ so the integral becomes
$$ \int_\pi^{2\pi} 2\cos u \,du\;=\;2\sin u\Big|_\pi^{2\pi} = 2\sin (2\pi)-2\sin(\pi)\,=\,0 - 0 = 0 $$

I simply changed the bounds of integration, so there's no need to "back-substitute". So it seems, as you proceeded in your evaluation of the definite integral, that your answer is indeed correct.

See, e.g. Wolfram|Alpha's computation:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

---

Visual representation of the integral:

[image]

*If we are looking to **calculate the area** between the x-axis and the curve, then we need to *split the integral* to compute the area below the x-axis, and the area above the x-axis: for $u$, the dividing point will be $\large\frac{3\pi}{2}$ (for $x$: $\large\frac{9\pi}{4}).$

$$\Big|\int_\pi^{\large\frac{3\pi}{2}} 2\cos u \,du\;\Big|\;\;+ \;\;\Big|\int_{\large\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi} 2\cos u \,du\;\Big|\;\; = \;\;\Big|2\sin u|_\pi^{3/2\pi}\Big|\;+\; \Big|2\sin u|_{3/2\pi}^{2\pi}\Big|\; =\; 2 + 2 = 4$$

Comment: You answered the OP in detailed. +

Comment: I see.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome, Belial! If you find an answer to be especially helpful, you can "accept" it by clicking on the "greyed-out" checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. Here is a slightly different approach, if you want.
Using the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$, we have $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$ so the integral becomes
$$
\int_\pi^{2\pi} 2\cos u du=2\sin (2\pi)-2\sin(\pi)=0 . 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Although @julien got the right fact about the definite integral, we should find a positive value for that. I mean we should consider the following integrals as well to find a real area: $$
\Big|\int_\pi^{3\pi/2}\Big|\;\;+\;\;\Big|\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\Big|  
$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! I'll edit to make bigger absolute value signs +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for the time.